The type initializer for 'iText.Commons.Actions.EventManager' threw an exception
I'm trying to build a simple PowerShell cmdlet that will use iText7 to open a PDF file and output the text. I've tried using the iText7Module from PowerShell Gallery, but the LocationTextExtractionStrategy that is part of iText7 is too specific on vertical location. I'd like to implement the approach here iText7 reading out lines in a wrong order to address it. The only functionality I'm looking to get out of iText7 is the text extraction, so I figured it would be best to build a custom cmdlet to do just that one thing (using the lax extraction strategy).
I've been incrementally building the cmdlet. Basically starting with a "Hello, World" cmdlet, I've been adding the needed iText7 commands. It worked until I tried to make the PdfDocument object. When I run the cmdlet, I get,

The type initializer for 'iText.Commons.Actions.EventManager' threw an exception.

I'm using Visual Studio Code. Pardon in advance, my C#/NET dev skills are pretty limited (all the rest of the heavy lifting of this project will get done in PowerShell).
using System;
using System.Management.Automation; 
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

namespace TestCmdlet{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "LaxPDFText")]

    public class LaxPDFText : PSCmdlet {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
        public string filePath {get; set;}

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
        public int laxRange {get; set;}

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
          WriteObject("filePath: " + filePath);
          WriteObject("laxRange: " + laxRange);
          try {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
            try {
              PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
              pdfDocument.Close();
              }
            catch (Exception e) {WriteObject("Couldn't create pdfDocument"); WriteObject(e.Message); WriteObject(e.StackTrace);}
            pdfReader.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception e) {WriteObject("Couldn't create pdfReader"); WriteObject(e.Message); WriteObject(e.StackTrace);}
        }
    }
}


Then attempting in PowerShell...
PS C:\Users\Van Drunens\documents> import-module TestCmdlet
PS C:\Users\Van Drunens\documents> Get-LaxPDFText -filePath "c:\users\van drunens\documents\test.pdf" -laxRange 5
filePath: c:\users\van drunens\documents\test.pdf
laxRange: 5
Couldn't create pdfDocument
The type initializer for 'iText.Commons.Actions.EventManager' threw an exception.
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Open(PdfVersion newPdfVersion)
   at TestCmdlet.LaxPDFText.BeginProcessing()

I'm perplexed at the error at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Open(PdfVersion newPdfVersion) referencing a type of PdfVersion.

Adding InnerException helped track down the problem assemblies. Some were missing, but the final problem is the nuget build for iText7 seems to have an incorrect reference?

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=4.0.2.0, ...

Looking at nuget, there is no such version. It appears there's some dll in iText7 that is referencing it (even though the iText7 project files don't as far as I can see).
I substituted the iText7 dlls found for iText7Module on PowerShell gallery and targeted 7.2.0 (which is what they are labeled) and it now works. The iText7 dlls from iText7Module labeled as 7.2.0 aren't the same as the ones with the same version from nuget. Not sure what is going on exactly, but it resolved the issue.

Likely the iText7 and iText7Module have different release cadences, so their versions may or may not match up (iText7Module may reference a different version of iText7 than its own version is). Depends on how the organization manages their releases.
